# trouble with passing static variable through functions

Tags: c++

I think I've just been doing too much too fast, I'm still taking the first course and it's early. I've googled and searched on this site, but even the answers to similar questions aren't clicking right now.

All I want to have happen is to keep my user input variables and pass them down to when they calculate then print, even writing it out sounds so basic but I'm stuck....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
void getTime12();
void getTime24();
void convert24to12();
void convert12to24();
void print24();
void print12();
void menu();

int main()
{

    int choice;

    do
    {

    // Display menu options
    menu();
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == '1')
    {
        getTime12();
        convert12to24();
        print24();
    }

    else if (choice == '2')
    {
        getTime24();
        convert24to12();
        print12();
    }

} while (choice != '99');

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    //Declare variabls to return
cout << endl;
cout << "1. To convert time from 12-hour notation to 24-hour notation."   << endl;
cout << "2. To convert time from 24-hour notation to 12-hour notation." << endl;
cout << "99. To quit the program." << endl << endl;
cout << "Your choice (1, 2, 99): ";
cout << endl << endl;
}


//function to get the hours

void getTime12()
{
static int get12Hrs, get12Mins, get12Secs;
static string AMPM = "AM";

//ask for the hour using cin
cout << "Enter the hours: ";
cin >> get12Hrs;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter minutes: ";
cin >> get12Mins;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter seconds: ";
cin >> get12Secs;
cout << endl;

//ask user for AM PM input
cout << "Enter AM or PM: ";
cin >> AMPM;

//For PM
if (AMPM == "PM" || AMPM == "Pm" || AMPM == "pm")
{
    AMPM = "PM";
}

}


void getTime24()
{
static int get24Hrs, get24Mins, get24Secs;
static string AMPM = "AM";

//ask for the hour using cin
cout << "Enter the hours: ";
cin >> get24Hrs;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter minutes: ";
cin >> get24Mins;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter seconds: ";
cin >> get24Secs;
cout << endl;

//ask user for AM PM input
cout << "Enter AM or PM: ";
cin >> AMPM;

//For PM
if (AMPM == "PM" || AMPM == "Pm" || AMPM == "pm")
{
    AMPM = "PM";
}

}

//Function to change to 24-hour notation
void convert24to12()
{
    if (get24Hrs < 12)
    {
        get24Hrs = get24Hrs;
        get24Mins = get24Mins;
        get24Secs = get24Secs;
    }
    if (AMPM == "PM")
    {
        get24Hrs = get24Hrs - 12;
        get24Mins = get24Mins;
        get24Secs = get24Secs;
    }
}

//Function to change to 12-hour notation
void convert12to24()
{
    if (get12Hrs > 12)
    {
        get12Hrs = get12Hrs;
        get12Mins = get12Mins;
        get12Secs = get12Secs;
    }
    if (AMPM == "PM")
    {
        get12Hrs = get12Hrs + 12;
        get12Mins = get12Mins;
        get12Secs = get12Secs;
    }
}



void print12()
{
    cout << "The 12-hour time is " << get24Hrs << ":";

    cout.width(2);
    cout.fill('0');

    cout << get24Mins << " " << get24Secs;
    cout << AMPM << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;

 }


void print24()
{
    cout << "The 24-hour time is " << get12Hrs << ":";

    cout.width(2);
    cout.fill('0');

    cout << get12Mins << " " << get12Secs;
    cout << AMPM << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;

}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to declare `get24Hrs` as global variable. I recommend you write a much smaller program to examine how global and static variables work.

Comment: my instructor will not allow global variables. so im looking for an alternative

Comment: Then you need to declare all variables in main() and pass them as parameters on every function call. You know how to do that?

Comment: void convert24to12(int &) .... or void convert24to12(int get24Hrs, string AMPM ...ect) ?

Comment: both will work. If he intentioned stated to PASS BY REFERENCE: then way number one. else, way number two. I will help you

Comment: I will pass by reference and see if i can get this to compile

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues in your code so I will do my best:

In your `main()`, `choice` is an `int` but you are checking if it's a `character` 1 or 2 or 99. this takes the `ASCI CODE` value of those characters which are equal to (I think) 49, 50, .. etc. Just remove the brackets if you want to check the integer value.

Also, you need to declare all your variables in `main()`, but then pass needed variables on every function call.

Also try to find a better naming so things don't get confusing. (See below)

Try to do all the `std::cout` statements in `main()`, and the calculations in functions. Just for a better practice.

This code is your code but compiles, you need to figure the rest out yourself and I will help if needed. This code pass variables *by value* and **NOT by reference**. Make sure that the logic is correct by Step-Over/Step-Into the code using F-10 and F-11 in Visual Studio. Hoover your mouse on all variables on every statement to see if the flow is what you desire. And Good luck!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


// Function Prototypes
void getTime12(string, int,int, int);
void getTime24(string, int, int, int);
void convert12to24(string, int, int, int);
void convert24to12(string, int, int, int);
void print24(string, int, int, int);
void print12(string, int, int, int);
void menu();

int main()
{
    static string AMPM = "AM";
    int get12Hrs = 0, get12Mins = 0, get12Secs = 0;
    int get24Hrs = 0, get24Mins = 0, get24Secs = 0;

    int choice;

    do
    {
        // Display menu options
        menu();
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            getTime12(AMPM, get12Hrs, get12Mins, get12Secs);
            convert12to24(AMPM, get12Hrs, get12Mins, get12Secs);
            print24(AMPM, get12Hrs, get12Mins, get12Secs);
        }

        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            getTime24(AMPM, get24Hrs, get24Mins, get24Secs);
            convert24to12(AMPM, get24Hrs, get24Mins, get24Secs);
            print12(AMPM, get24Hrs, get24Mins, get24Secs);
        }

    } while (choice != 99);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    //Declare variabls to return
    cout << endl;
    cout << "1. To convert time from 12-hour notation to 24-hour notation." << endl;
    cout << "2. To convert time from 24-hour notation to 12-hour notation." << endl;
    cout << "99. To quit the program." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Your choice (1, 2, 99): ";
    cout << endl << endl;
}

//function to get the hours
void getTime12(string AMPM, int get12Hrs, int get12Mins, int get12Secs)
{

    //ask for the hour using cin
    cout << "Enter the hours: ";
    cin >> get12Hrs;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter minutes: ";
    cin >> get12Mins;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter seconds: ";
    cin >> get12Secs;
    cout << endl;

    //ask user for AM PM input
    cout << "Enter AM or PM: ";
    cin >> AMPM;

    //For PM
    if (AMPM == "PM" || AMPM == "Pm" || AMPM == "pm")
    {
        AMPM = "PM";
    }

}

void getTime24(string AMPM, int get24Hrs, int get24Mins, int get24Secs)
{

    //ask for the hour using cin
    cout << "Enter the hours: ";
    cin >> get24Hrs;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter minutes: ";
    cin >> get24Mins;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter seconds: ";
    cin >> get24Secs;
    cout << endl;

    //ask user for AM PM input
    cout << "Enter AM or PM: ";
    cin >> AMPM;

    //For PM
    if (AMPM == "PM" || AMPM == "Pm" || AMPM == "pm")
    {
        AMPM = "PM";
    }

}

//Function to change to 24-hour notation
void convert24to12(string AMPM, int get24Hrs, int get24Mins, int get24Secs)
{
    if (get24Hrs < 12)
    {
        get24Hrs = get24Hrs;
        get24Mins = get24Mins;
        get24Secs = get24Secs;
    }
    if (AMPM == "PM")
    {
        get24Hrs = get24Hrs - 12;
        get24Mins = get24Mins;
        get24Secs = get24Secs;
    }
}

//Function to change to 12-hour notation
void convert12to24(string AMPM, int get12Hrs, int get12Mins, int get12Secs)
{
    if (get12Hrs > 12)
    {
        get12Hrs = get12Hrs;
        get12Mins = get12Mins;
        get12Secs = get12Secs;
    }
    if (AMPM == "PM")
    {
        get12Hrs = get12Hrs + 12;
        get12Mins = get12Mins;
        get12Secs = get12Secs;
    }
}

void print12(string AMPM, int get24Hrs, int get24Mins, int get24Secs)
{
    cout << "The 12-hour time is " << get24Hrs << ":";

    cout.width(2);
    cout.fill('0');

    cout << get24Mins << " " << get24Secs;
    cout << AMPM << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;

}

void print24(string AMPM, int get12Hrs, int get12Mins, int get12Secs)
{
    cout << "The 24-hour time is " << get12Hrs << ":";

    cout.width(2);
    cout.fill('0');

    cout << get12Mins << " " << get12Secs;
    cout << AMPM << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;

}
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help, I know I'm making mistakes but I will keep going. I'm working on it right now

Comment: @Chris As long as you keep going :)

Comment: This code doesn't work. Maybe you are thinking of passing by reference, for example `void getTime12(string &AMPM, int &get12Hrs, int &get12Mins, int &get12Secs)`

Comment: We agreed it compiles and he will do the rest. @barmakshemirani and he mentioned above that he will try by reference

Comment: I can't read the fine print. I see get functions which are pass by value. If that's some form of tutoring technique I'll leave this be.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I got to wait for his questions/updates